# Claiming US citizenship from UK. Anyone done this?

Tags: usa, citizenship

I would like to know if anyone has been in the same situation as me and has a little guidance. Basically I'm a British citizen, living in the UK. My father is a US citizen. He lived half of his life in the US and half in Israel, he's a dual national. Under US law I may have claim to citizenship if one parent is a US citizen. I believed I did have claim to this so I made an appointment at the US embassy in London to see if I did, and if so would also receive my first American passport. One of the requirements for claiming this citizenship is that you must show evidence of the parents physical presence I the US for more than 5 years, along with other stuff. At my appointment I was told I may have claim, I just needed to go find more evidence of my fathers presence in the US; receipts, doctors notes etc it took a little longer than expected to find this stuff as my father currently lives in Israel. I collected all the stuff and posted it to the embassy over 6 weeks ago. I'm yet to hear anything back. There is no uk number available to call anymore just an email, which only respond with very robotic unhelpful emails such as 'we will contact you when someone has looked at your application'. Has anyone been through this process themselves and could tell me how long it all took for them? I've had to cancel flights to the states and plans to visit family members while waiting, my appointment at the embassy was way back in February.

I know it's a long complicated process so don't mind waiting, just wondering how long others waited.

Answer (score 4):

I know of people who did that, 2-3 months is definitely a reasonable time period. It may take longer for them to verify all the documents you've submitted.